# Reusing connections with reqwest

Tags: rest, rust, https, reqwest

I need to issue a long sequence of REST calls to the same server (let's call it `myapi.com`). At the moment, I am using the Rust library `reqwest` as follows:

- I create a `reqwest::Client` with all default settings.
- For each REST call:

  - I use `client.post("https://myapi.com/path/to/the/api")` to create a `reqwest::RequestBuilder`.
  - I configure the `RequestBuilder` to obtain a `reqwest::Request`.
  - I `send()` the `Request`, read the `reqwest::Response`.
  - I drop everything except the `Client`, start again.

I read in the docs that `reqwest` is supposed to pool connections within the same `Client`. Given that I always reuse the same `Client`, I would expect the first API call to take some more (owing to the initial TCP and HTTPS handshakes). However, I observe always a consistent, quite high latency across all requests. So, I am wondering if connections are reused at all, or re-established every time. If they are not, how do I get to recycle the same connection? I feel that latency would be drastically reduced if I could save myself some roundtrips.

Comment: Can't you track the accepted TCP connections on your server, or use tcpdump/wireshark in order to detect the SYN/FIN segments? (just to be certain that these multiple connections actually happen before refactoring the code)

Comment: This is a very good point! The server's not mine, sadly. I'm not very expert on low-level networking, can you elaborate on the wireshark strategy you proposed?

Answer (score 1):

(could not comment, have to leave a new answer)

[ynn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76269482/23324912) is pretty helpful. However, it's not correct about the log part, at least for now and for me.

It would still create 4 connections rather than 2.

According to
https://users.rust-lang.org/t/hyper-reqwest-connection-not-being-kept-alive/10895/3, you need to "read to end". And after doing so, it works!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior depends on whether you're using `reqwest::blocking::Client` (sync) or `reqwest::Client` (async).

Whether or not the existing connection is reused can be checked by enabling debug log.

### `reqwest::blocking::Client`

When using synchronous API, just reusing a client means reusing a connection.

This is because, at the second (or third or ...) time we use the client, it is guaranteed the first call has completed and we have a connection.

```rust
use std::env;

use reqwest::blocking::Client;

fn main() {
    env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "debug");
    env_logger::init();

    let client = Client::new();
    for _ in 0..3 {
        //calls an API which returns a random string
        let res = client
            .get("https://ciprand.p3p.repl.co/api?len=10&count=1")
            .send()
            .unwrap();
        println!("{}", res.text().unwrap());
    }
}
```

```
[2023-05-17T07:11:13Z DEBUG reqwest::connect] starting new connection: https://ciprand.p3p.repl.co/
{"Strings":["fa749eda765"],"Count":1,"Length":10}
{"Strings":["dd0a8bfdc57"],"Count":1,"Length":10}
{"Strings":["cdedd8e3982"],"Count":1,"Length":10}
```

(Only one `starting new connection` is printed.)

### `reqwest::Client`

When using asynchronous API, just reusing a client does **NOT** mean reusing a connection.

This is because, at the second (or third or ...) time we use the client, it is **NOT** guaranteed the first call has completed and we have a connection.

<sub>(The code below is for experiment purpose: never write an async code like this.)</sub>

```rust
use std::{env, sync::Arc};

use reqwest::Client;

async fn call(url: &str, client: Arc<Client>) {
    client.get(url).send().await.unwrap();
    println!("completed");
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "debug");
    env_logger::init();

    let client = Arc::new(Client::new());

    for _ in 0..2 {
        tokio::spawn(call(
            "https://ciprand.p3p.repl.co/api?len=10&count=1",
            client.clone(),
        ));
    }

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000));

    for _ in 0..2 {
        tokio::spawn(call(
            "https://ciprand.p3p.repl.co/api?len=10&count=1",
            client.clone(),
        ));
    }

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000));
}
```

```
[2023-05-17T07:14:25Z DEBUG reqwest::connect] starting new connection: https://ciprand.p3p.repl.co/
[2023-05-17T07:14:25Z DEBUG reqwest::connect] starting new connection: https://ciprand.p3p.repl.co/
completed
completed
completed
completed
```

(Only two `starting new connection` are printed. This is because, at the third and fourth time we use the client, the first (or maybe the second) call has completed *by chance* and we have a connection.)